# SQL Server date range, monthly or quarterly

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a list of dates in a SQL Server table, and need to figure out a few separate themes about them:

Firstly, are the dates monthly or quarterly? The dates always start on the first of the month.

E.g. one sequence may be `01/01/13, 01/02/13, 01/03/13, 01/04/13, 01/05/13` therefore monthly (UK)

E.g. another sequence may be `01/12/12, 01/03/13, 01/06/13, 01/09/13, 01/12/13` therefore quarterly (UK)

And secondly, which may be solved by the first, are all the dates present? eg no gaps. One way I went around solving this was to say it is either monthly / quarterly or no idea, but that was in C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DATEDIFF()` function to compare two dates, and you can use a self-join and the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to compare dates from different rows:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) RN
              FROM Table1)
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,a.dt,b.dt)
FROM cte a
JOIN cte b
 ON a.RN = b.RN-1
```

If you are using SQL 2012 you can use the `LEAD()` function to compare values from different rows:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day,dt,LEAD(dt,1) OVER(ORDER BY dt)) AS Days
       ,DATEDIFF(quarter,dt,LEAD(dt,1) OVER(ORDER BY dt)) AS Quarters
FROM Table2
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/680be/3/0)

Comment: I kind of see where you are coming from with that one. RowNumber Over is a good place to start, thanks